# Memory gap between a statically allocated array and a variable

Tags: c, gcc

Following is a toy program that inhibits a buffer overflow vulnerability:

```
#include < stdio.h > 
#include < string.h >

  /* Returns 1 if pass is
   * the correct password, otherwise 0 */
  int check_correct_passwd(char * pass) {
    /* Omitted */
    /* Very complex logic */
    return 0;
  }

void print_secret_key() {
  int c;
  FILE * file;
  file = fopen("/home/alice/master-secret.txt", "r");
  if (file) {
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
      putchar(c);
    fclose(file);
  } else {
    printf("Failed to open master-secret.txt");
  }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  int decision;
  char passwd[16];

  if (argc < 2) {
    printf("usage: %s password\n", argv[0]);
    return 0;
  }

  decision = check_correct_passwd(argv[1]);
  strcpy(passwd, argv[1]);

  printf("%d\n", decision);
  printf("%s\n", argv[1]);

  if (decision) {
    printf("Access granted to the document with passwd %s!\n", passwd);
    print_secret_key();
  } else
    printf("Access denied.\n");
  return 0;
}
```

OS is `Linux 4.14.76`. Compiler version is `gcc 8.2.1`.

I'm compiling this program with `gcc getkey.c -ggdb -fno-stack-protector -o getkey`, basically places debugging symbols and disables the stack canary.

I expect this program to print out the master key upon receiving an input that has a length greater than 16, as it would overwrite decision and force the branch to evaluate to true. However, the required length is much greater than 16. GDB shows the addresses of these variables, and contents of them after executing `strcpy(passwd, argv[1])` as follows:

```
(gdb) print &passwd
$17 = (char (*)[16]) 0x7fffffffe0b0
(gdb) print &decision
$18 = (int *) 0x7fffffffe0cc
(gdb) x/16b &passwd
0x7fffffffe0b0: "01234567890123456"
0x7fffffffe0c2: "\377\377\377\177"
0x7fffffffe0c7: ""
0x7fffffffe0c8: ""
0x7fffffffe0c9: ""
0x7fffffffe0ca: ""
0x7fffffffe0cb: ""
0x7fffffffe0cc: ""
0x7fffffffe0cd: ""
0x7fffffffe0ce: ""
0x7fffffffe0cf: ""
0x7fffffffe0d0: "\360RUUUU"
0x7fffffffe0d7: ""
0x7fffffffe0d8: "#\322\337\367\377\177"
0x7fffffffe0df: ""
0x7fffffffe0e0: ""
```

The memory gap between `passwd` and `decision` is `0x1c` = 28 bytes. There are extra 12 bytes that I cannot explain their existence. What is the explanation of such a long gap?

Comment: The compiler's free to put these things wherever it sees fit. It could be 12 bytes, or a hundred trillion. In practice the amount of junk on the stack often depends on a number of factors, but most importantly the optimization level when compiling. `-O3` can change everything dramatically.

Comment: This question is pointless to even speculate about without a specific system in mind. Is it Windows, Linux, something else? What version of OS and compiler? Etc.

Comment: @tadman: Well, I suppose I'm asking about those factors. The compiler is obviously isn't bound by anything in regards of memory placement, though be it 12 bytes or hundred trillion, a compiler wouldn't place an arbitrary amount of bytes between variables for no reason.

Comment: @Lundin: I added the details you asked. Let me know if there is something else under that "etc".

Comment: The compiler often works in mysterious ways, and the hardware sometimes imposes constraints as well. ARM pointer signing is one example of how the pointers might be just about anywhere in the 64-bit address space, so a hundred trillion bytes of offset is not out of the question. There's no reason to presume they show up in any particular place. Security techniques like [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) can and will mess up your expectations because that's what they're designed to do.